# azure-media-services - Use existing CDN

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-cdn

I cannot link an existing CDN that we use for the streaming endpoint. Should I be able to do this? I can only enable the default endpoint which creates a CDN profile called AzureMediaStreamingPlatformCdnProfile-StandardVerizon. Is it possible to link the streaming endpoint to an existing CDN?

Answer (score 0):

From the Azure Media Services UI or API you can enable Azure CDN and use an existing Azure CDN profile or create a new CDN profile. A CDN profile represents a specific Azure CDN SKU and specific CDN provider (e.g. Verizon). Azure Media Services then handles the creation/deletion of the Azure CDN endpoint - which represents the CDN configuration. Azure Media Services API / UI does not allow one to select an existing CDN endpoint to be used with a streaming endpoint. The use of an existing CDN endpoint is only possible by using the Azure CDN API/UI to set the origin for the CDN endpoint to point to the streaming endpoint hostname. There are the following downsides to this approach - 1) You will need to use the CDN endpoint hostname (e.g. xxxxx.azureedge.net) to make use of the CDN 2) You will see data transfer charges for CDN cache fill traffic - i.e. traffic from the streaming endpoint to individual CDN POPs. This is typically a small % of your overall charges assuming you have a high cache-hit ratio (e.g. +90%) for content on the CDN.

Comment: Thanks Anton - Thats really useful. With a bit more testing i have also found out that the only way the Media service can see the CDN is if its in the same resource group. So I am settling for allowing the media service to create the streaming endpoint on my CDN. Once the endpoint is created I will add a custom domain and HTTPS.